# Unable to run program using Pycharm Debugger, but normal Run works fine when using opencv - [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I have checked a lot of similar posts where users were having issues with the Pycharm debugger not working, but running it using the run button working fine, but none of them applied to an issue with opencv.

Here is my simple script:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('../FGVC/data/balloon/1548266469.88633.png')
image_2 = cv2.imread('../FGVC/data/balloon_mask/1.jpg')



cv2.imshow('img', image)
cv2.imshow('img2', image_2)
yo = np.bitwise_and(image, image_2)
ye = np.bitwise_or(image, image_2)
cv2.imshow('combined', yo)
cv2.imshow('combinedd', ye)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I get the following exception whenever I import cv2 through the python debugger.

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/config-3.6.py'`

I am using an anaconda virtual environment running Python 3.6. I did check that the cv2 directory and indeed there is no config-3.6.py file, but there was a config-3.py file, so I duplicated that and called it config-3.6.py, but then I started running into the following issue:

`(<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError(b'LD_LIBRARY_PATH',), <traceback object at 0x7fe97dd32ac8>)`

This is the content of my config-3.6.py file.

```
PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS = [
    LOADER_DIR
] + PYTHON_EXTENSIONS_PATHS

ci_and_not_headless = False

try:
    from .version import ci_build, headless

    ci_and_not_headless = ci_build and not headless
except:
    pass

# the Qt plugin is included currently only in the pre-built wheels
if sys.platform.startswith("linux") and ci_and_not_headless:
    os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "qt", "plugins"
    )

# Qt will throw warning on Linux if fonts are not found
if sys.platform.startswith("linux") and ci_and_not_headless:
    os.environ["QT_QPA_FONTDIR"] = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "qt", "fonts"
    )
```

**Edit**: what is also strange is that after the exception being raised the rest of the open-cv script works as expected the same way it works with the run button.

Comment: maybe debuger use different path to Python. If you have `config-3.py` then copy it to `config-3.6.py` and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue was that I had made it so the Pycharm debugger would break "On Raise" of an exception for a different project and the settings carried over to this project.

I just unchecked the "On Raise" option and the problem was solved.
[image]